# Save records in Configuration Database

Tags: sharepoint, splist

I need to save some settings in sharepoint and i could access the datas from any webapplications. Shall i go for configuration database or is there any other option.

Comment: Can you better elaborate your question ?

Answer (score 3):

its better to go for a Custom List to save any settings regarding your project/assignment.  Its not the best idea to manually query/change the configuration database. Take a look at how to [create a custom list with content types](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/02/08/A-Quicker-Way-to-Create-Custom-SharePoint-List-Templates.aspx). Or the other option is to go for [property bags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798491.aspx) regarding the general settings for the project!

Comment: If i go for custom list the web application may deleted at any time. So i cannot retrieve my datas.

Comment: Property bags are option for you as suggested by me and as well Anna

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use property bag to store settings for details see the link attached

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798491.aspx

http://spg.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20of%20the%20Configuration%20Manager&version=3